# New android developer, need help getting emulator to run HelloWorld

Tags: android, eclipse, android-emulator

I just got the bignerdranch android book, and already, I cant get my emulator to work. This is not exclusive to Big Nerd Ranch, since even the default hellworld wont run... I get the following in my console box.

```
[2013-12-18 13:17:40 - HelloWorld] ------------------------------
[2013-12-18 13:17:40 - HelloWorld] Android Launch!
[2013-12-18 13:17:40 - HelloWorld] adb is running normally.
[2013-12-18 13:17:40 - HelloWorld] Performing com.example.helloworld.HelloActivity activity launch
[2013-12-18 13:17:40 - HelloWorld] Automatic Target Mode: launching new emulator with compatible AVD 
'Nexus_API_17'
[2013-12-18 13:17:40 - HelloWorld] Launching a new emulator with Virtual Device 'Nexus_API_17'
[2013-12-18 13:17:56 - Emulator] creating window 0 0 577 1025
[2013-12-18 13:17:56 - Emulator] eglMakeCurrent failed
[2013-12-18 13:18:23 - Emulator] eglMakeCurrent failed
[2013-12-18 13:18:23 - Emulator] FrameBuffer::post eglMakeCurrent failed
[2013-12-18 13:18:24 - Emulator] eglMakeCurrent failed
[2013-12-18 13:18:24 - Emulator] FrameBuffer::post eglMakeCurrent failed
```

I have tried redownloading eclipse, I have tried both 32 and 64 bit versions. I have tried making the emulator different rams, different phones, different sdk versions. I have tried running as admin as well. I am out of ideas on what I can do.

PS: I have also scoured the web looking for solutions, and did just try the end ADB task, then relaunch eclipse and try again.. no success

Comment: https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28817

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=28817 - Refer this

Comment: Hrmm thanks. I have done most of those things, and im on windows 7. However, I cannot find emulator-user.ini on windows to delete. Still looking for some sort of emulator ini file to delete, will update when I find it

Comment: Consider testing on a real device... for most purposes it's a lot more convenient.

Comment: Did you restart ur Eclipse after setting your android dev?

Comment: Ok I will try a real device, and ive restarted eclipse a ton at this point just trying to get it to work, so i think im safe there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FIXED IT! So the way I got it to work for me, and this is simply so that other people can read this in the future if they have the same issue, is:

1) I had to switch to 32bit instead of 64.

2) I had to run the emulator (which still throws errors), and wait for it to load fully.

3) After it loaded fully, I then run the emulator a second time while the first is still opened.

4) I get the following errors:

```
 [2013-12-19 15:20:35 - Emulator] WARNING: Data partition already in use. Changes will      
 not persist!

 [2012-09-02 15:20:35 - Emulator] WARNING: Cache partition already in use. Changes will 
 not persist!
```

followed by:

```
 [2013-12-19 15:21:46 - HelloWorld] New emulator found: emulator-5554

 [2013-12-19 15:21:46 - HelloWorld] Waiting for HOME ('android.process.acore') to be 
 launched...
```

5) Then you close the first emulator and the new one opens and runs the app...

Answer (score 0):

Please checkout how much ram size you define for emulator; it should be greater than or equal to 256MiB. You can also verify this in the logcat files.

Comment: I have it set at 512 per bignerdranch book instructions.

Comment: also i ran it again and logcat didnt report anything? Only console did?

http://tinypic.com/r/2afg1h4/5

Comment: Please open DDMS view and select your device from it. You can see log cat